# How to center a navigation bar with CSS or HTML?

Tags: html, css, nav, centering

I am having difficulty with centering the navigation bar on [this page](http://wpbeta.nfshost.com/contest).

I tried `nav { margin: 0 auto; }` and a bunch of other ways, but I still can't center it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "centering this navigation bar"?

Comment: It is centred. It's just that the child elements aren't.

Comment: @David Thomas - So the child element is causing the main nav not to be centered?

Comment: No, because you can't see the `background-color` of the menu, the children are causing the menu to *look* not to be centred. Add a `background-color` to the menu and it seems to be fine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
#nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

It should work, I tested it in your site.

[image]

Comment: I tested it in your site using Firebug and it worked. I can show you a screen capture :)

Comment: Actually, it works adding only `display: inline-block;`. I tested it again.

Comment: @morgar - any ideas on how to get the child element to line up with the main one?

Comment: @morgar - yes, contest has a child element

Comment: What has inline-block to do with centering? A bit absurd that it works. But it does.

Answer (score 13):

Add some CSS:

```
div#nav{
  text-align: center;
}
div#nav ul{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Anyway to get the child element to align with the word above?

Comment: You can set ´text-align: left´ on your child element.

Answer (score 4):

If you have your navigation `<ul>` with class #nav
Then you need to put that `<ul>` item within a div container.  Make your div container the 100% width. and set the text-align: element to center in the div container.  Then in your `<ul>` set that class to have 3 particular elements: text-align:center; position: relative; and display: inline-block;

that should center it.

Answer (score 2):

Just add :

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `nav` `div` is actually centered correctly. But the `ul` inside is not. Give the `ul` a specific width and center that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix it I have looked for the code or trick how to center nav menu and found the real solutions it works for all browsers and for my friends ;)

Here is how I have done:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div maincontainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: ___px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

and do not forget to set `doctype html5`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use float and inline-block to center your nav like the following:

```
nav li {
   float: left;
}
nav {
   display: inline-block;
}
```