# How to move navigation bar to the horizontal center?

Tags: html, css, center, positioning

I would like to move the following navigation bar to the horizontal center, but don't know how!? Any idea?

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 350px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #FEDD19;
  float: left;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FEDD19;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ...but try removing any floats.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrap the `<ul>` into a `div` with fixed width and apply `margin: 0px auto;` to that div.

```css
body {
 background-color: black;
}
#nav {
 width: 440px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 border: 1px solid white;
}
.clear {
 clear: both;
}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding-top: 30px;
}

li a {
 display: block;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 border-left: 1px solid #FEDD19;
 float: left;
}

li a:hover {
 color: #000000;
 background-color: #FEDD19;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

[How to center a navigation bar with CSS or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995405/how-to-center-a-navigation-bar-with-css-or-html)

Answer (score 0):

#### Navigation bar to center

```css
.ul {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;  

  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;       
}

.li {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;       

  -webkit-align-self: center;       
  align-self: center;
}

a .li:hover {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FEDD19;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="ul">
  <a><div class="li">1</div></a>
  <a><div class="li">2</div></a>
  <a><div class="li">3</div></a>  
  <a><div class="li">4</div></a>
  <a><div class="li">5</div></a>     
</div>
```