# How to center the navigation menu on my Wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to centre the menu on my Wordpress site with CSS:

http://thewholesomebakery.co.uk/

I'm aware that I have to remove `float:left`; but then solutions seem to vary from `theme` to `theme`.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center a navigation bar with CSS or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995405/how-to-center-a-navigation-bar-with-css-or-html)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this css:

```css
.site-bar .nav { 
    width: 100%;
    float: none; 
    text-align: center; 
}

.navigation > li { 
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the float and add `margin: auto;`. The page of the w3c about [centering things](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) is an absolute must-read for any web developper.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to:

```
.site-bar .nav {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

that should center the top navigation!